# Reducing borders in matplotlib quiver

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm willing to plot a simple vector field using the following code:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_quiver(vx, vy, fp):
    plt.figure()

    x_steps, y_steps = vx.shape

    x, y = numpy.meshgrid(numpy.linspace(0, x_steps, x_steps), numpy.linspace(0, y_steps, y_steps))
    m = numpy.sqrt(numpy.power(vx, 2) + numpy.power(vy, 2))

    fig = plt.quiver(x, y, vx, vy, m)
    plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')

    l, r, b, t = plt.axis()
    dx, dy = r-l, t-b
    plt.axis([l-0.1*dx, r+0.1*dx, b-0.1*dy, t+0.1*dy])

    plt.savefig(fp, format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

What I don't get is why I have wider top and right borders, and how to **adjust** it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matplotlib` seems to get the next round number after the size of your vector field.
Here `r, t = 70, 70`.
To make sure your problem does not depend on the scaling of `matplotlib`, use
`plt.axis([-0.1*x_steps, 1.1*x_steps, -0.1*y_steps, 1.1*y_steps])`